# Simple PHP Recursion Test Failing

Tags: php, recursion

I am attempting a basic recursion to create multi-dimensional arrays based on the values of an inputed array.

The recursion works by checking for a value we shall call it "recursion" to start the loop and looks for another value we'll call it "stop_recursion" to end.

Basically taking this array

```
array('One', 'Two', 'recursion', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', 'stop_recursion', 'Six', 'Seven')
```

And making this array

```
array('One', 'Two', array('Three', 'Four', 'Five'), 'Six', 'Seven')
```

The code I have for it so far is as follows

```
function testRecrusion($array, $child = false)
{
    $return = array();

    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if ($value == 'recursion') {
            unset($array[$key]);
            $new = testRecrusion($array, true);
            $array = $new['array'];
            $return[] = $new['return'];
        } else {
            if ($value == 'stop_recursion') {
                unset($array[$key]);
                if ($child) {
                    return array('return' => $return, 'array' => $array);
                }
            } else {
                unset($array[$key]);
                $return[] = $value;
            }
        }
    }

    return $return;
}
```

But the output from that is

```
Array
(
    [0] => One
    [1] => Two
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Three
            [1] => Four
            [2] => Five
        )

    [3] => Three
    [4] => Four
    [5] => Five
    [6] => Six
    [7] => Seven
)
```

I guess the real question is...will an array values continuously loop through the first values given from the initial call or once the new array is returned and set will it loop through that new array. I know the answer is basically right here saying that yes it will continue the old array value, but shouldn't this work vice-versa?

Any help will be appreciated :)

------------ edit -------------------

I might as well add that while I can perform this action using a much simpler method, this needs to be recursively checked since this will be ported to a string parser that could have a infinite number of child arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you return inside the recursion, you need to return both the inner array and the index from which to continue searching for elements so that you don't look at the same element twice. Try this instead:

```
function testRecursionImpl($array, $i)
{
    $return = array();

    for (; $i < sizeof($array); ++$i) {
        if ($array[$i] == 'recursion') {
            $new = testRecursionImpl($array, $i + 1);
            $return[] = $new[0];
            $i = $new[1];
        } else if ($array[$i] == 'stop_recursion') {
            return array($return, $i);
        } else {
            $return[] = $array[$i];
        }
    }

    return array($return, $i);
}

function testRecursion($array)
{
    $result = testRecursionImpl($array, 0);
    return $result[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have in the code above is that you correctly detect when you should call this function recursively but once it finishes running and you append the results to output array you just pick next element (which is the first element that recursive call will get) and append it to output array. What you probably want to do is when you detect that you should run your function recursively you should skip all other characters until you find your stop word (`stop_recursion`). Obviously the problem will become harder if you allow multi-level recursion then you may need to even skip some stopwords because they could be from the different level call.

Still I don't know why you want such a feature. Maybe you would explain what are you trying to achieve. I'm pretty sure there's another, simpler way of doing it.

Comment: I have created something similar to this above, and while it does work it is not efficient enough to use for larger arrays more than a few MB's in size.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than helping with your homework, I would suggest you start with getting rid of this line:

`foreach ($array as $key => $value) {`

You should just pass in your array, and check for being at the end of the array, since it can't really be infinite, to know when you are done.

Comment: I surely would like to know what school you have attended that will give you PHP has homework.

I am assuming since I made the question simple and wrote out a simplified version of a pre-existing class, that I am therefore a student and have no clue on the fundamentals of PHP.

Comments like these are always a great reason I stop using many sites no matter how helpful they really are... 

I don't see how you determined that it could not be infinite, unless limited by the resources of the computer performing the processing?

Comment: @Paco - Schools do use PHP for homework, since it is a commonly used language and free and doesn't require compiling.

Comment: @nwhiting - You can search this site for tags PHP and homework, but here is one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276602/php-get-url-contents-and-search-for-string

Comment: @nwhiting - Your recursion is for an array, and PHP doesn't do tail-recursion that I know of, so how many iterations you can make it limited to the stack.

Comment: This does not give me the explanation why you decided to automatically flag my question as homework and give me a response that is completely useless.

Comment: @nwhiting - It sounds like a homework question, that is all. And I did give a suggestion as to one problem in your code.

Comment: @james - Well then I quess we both learned something new today then haven't we.

PHP doesnt do tail-recursion and Do not judge a book by its cover ... :)

Comment: @nwhiting - I choose to err on the side of safety, where giving someone the answer to their question if it is homework being the worst solution, so I will state that I think it is homework, then give suggestions. Too many people expect SO to do their homework for them, unfortunately.

Comment: @James Black, I understand you call this question "homework". I think I have to be happy that different languages were used at the University I went to.

Comment: @Paco - When I was an undergrad I studied C/C++ and Ada for my coursework, but I have seen questions here in PHP for homework. It may be community colleges moreso than universities, but if it sounds like a homework question, I treat it as such, but I will mention my assumption.

Answer (score 0):

Let me give it a try

```
function testRecursion($arr){
    $return = array();
    $recurlevel = 0;
    foreach ($arr as $v) {
      if($v == 'stop_recursion'){
        $recurlevel--;
      }
      if($recurlevel == 0){
        if(isset($current)){
          $return[] = testRecursion($current);
          unset($current);
        }else{
          if($v != 'recursion'){
            $return[] = $v;
          }
        }
      }else{
        if(!isset($current)){
           $current = array();
        }
        $current[] = $v;
      }
      if($v == 'recursion'){
        $recurlevel++;
      }
    }

    return $return;
}
```

Alright nicely done. This will help even if the recursion and stop_recursion are nested in another. See example:

code.php:

```
<pre><?php

function testRecursion($arr){
    $return = array();
    $recurlevel = 0;
    foreach ($arr as $v) {
      if($v == 'stop_recursion'){
        $recurlevel--;
      }
      if($recurlevel == 0){
        if(isset($current)){
          $return[] = testRecursion($current);
          unset($current);
        }else{
        if($v != 'recursion'){
          $return[] = $v;
        }
        }
      }else{
        if(!isset($current)){
           $current = array();
        }
          $current[] = $v;
      }
      if($v == 'recursion'){
        $recurlevel++;
      }
    }

    return $return;
}

$a = array('One', 'Two', 'recursion', 'Three', 'recursion', 'Four' , 'stop_recursion', 'Five', 'stop_recursion', 'Six', 'Seven');
var_dump(testRecursion($a));

?>
```

Browser output:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "One"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "Two"
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "Three"
    [1]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) "Four"
    }
    [2]=>
    string(4) "Five"
  }
  [3]=>
  string(3) "Six"
  [4]=>
  string(5) "Seven"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your question for the recursive solution has already been answered  ...might I offer a stack-based solution?

```
$x = array('a', 'b', 'recursion', 'cI', 'cII', 'cIII', 'recursion', 'cIV1', 'cIV2', 'cIV2', 'stop_recursion', 'stop_recursion', 'd', 'e');

$result = array();
$stack = array(&$result);
foreach($x as $e) {
  if ( 'recursion'===$e ) {
    array_unshift($stack, array());
    $stack[1][] = &$stack[0];
  }
  else if ( 'stop_recursion'===$e ) {
    array_shift($stack);
  }
  else {
    $stack[0][] = $e;
  }
}

var_dump($result);
```

prints

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "a"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "b"
  [2]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "cI"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "cII"
    [2]=>
    string(4) "cIII"
    [3]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) "cIV1"
      [1]=>
      string(4) "cIV2"
      [2]=>
      string(4) "cIV2"
    }
  }
  [3]=>
  string(3) "d"
  [4]=>
  string(5) "e"
}
```